# Python webscraping with Chromium browser cannot load Javascript but Chrome can

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, chromium, python-requests-html

I'm trying to webscrape a particular url using requests-html module which uses Chromium browser. However Chromium couldn't load what seem to be the Javascript portion and triggers timeout error. I thought html.render() would have rendered any Javascript code. I tested another python script using Selenium (with Google Chrome webdriver) and it ran perfectly.

So I tried to launch Chromium.exe manually (from %localappdata%\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium) and browse the url directly, it takes forever to load the Javascript portion. My Chromium version is [71.0.3542.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)] and it was installed the first time I ran my python script below. What should I do to make Chromium support Javascript preferably from within the python script?

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

webURL = "https://mphonline.com/collections/architecture-landscaping"
session = HTMLSession(pyppeteer_kwargs = {'handleSIGINT' : False,
                               'handleSIGTERM': False,
                               'handleSIGHUP': False,
                               'headless': False,
                               }
                           )

root = session.get(webURL)
root.html.render(timeout= 30, keep_page=True)    # default timeout is 8sec

titlesxpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'boost-sd__product-title')]"
titles = root.html.xpath(titlesxpath)  # find title element
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)

session.close()
```

Comment: could it be that chromium version 71.0.3542.0 is from 2018? `What should I do to make Chromium support Javascript` Chromium has supported javascript from version 1 and before - of course, 5 year old chromium probably doesn't support modern javascript

Comment: Thanks for the info. I assumed pyppeteer would download the latest stable Chromium version but after you mentioned it, did some research and found it's always the same default version downloaded. Installing and directing pyppeteer to use a particular Chromium version is not so straightforward as well, but finally got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Took a while to figure out how to install latest Chromium and finally got my script working based on hints from:

https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer/issues/291

https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html

**Step1**: Go to  https://chromium.cypress.io/  and find the latest Chromium version for your Windows platform (x86 or x64), currently it's 121.0.6157.1. Click on "Get downloads" and find the **base version** number, currently it's 1231099. Download the "chrome-win.zip" file.

**Step2**: Delete all older base version folders in **%localappdata%\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium**, then create new base version folder **%localappdata%\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\1231099**. Finally unzip the file "chrome-win.zip" here. Also delete all temporary folders in **%localappdata%\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\.dev_profile** just in case.

**Step3**: In Windows System Environment Variable, create new Variable name "PYPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION" with value equal to the base revision number "1231099". Then restart computer.

**Step4**: Run your python script. Chromium should support latest Javascript code.